# Three.js: how to get position of external object added by jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I am using 360 background image. 
Added a 2d Image using jquery. User can drag 2d image also. 
I need to get 2d Image position.
2d image gives position using Jquery but this position will not work for me because i have to add this position in database. and three.js object position is different then jquery provided position. 
I need position of 2d image just like we get position of object .
e.g.

```
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(threeimg);
            var materiallinks = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture });
            var object = new THREE.Mesh(geometrylinks, materiallinks);
            scene.add(object);
            var a=object.position.x;
```

In above code i have added object in scene then getting position in a variable.
My concern is how to get position of external jquery object. 
[image]

Comment: Is that so-called "jquery object" an HTML-element, or a sprite in the scene, or a plane in the scene?

Comment: its just html element with drag feature. i have not added it in scene.

Comment: _"because i have to add this position in database. and three.js object position is different then jquery provided position. "_ This is the most enigmatic part of the question. Could you provide more explanation of what you get and what you want to achieve?